ChromeDriverManager().install() occurs TimeoutError and no response
I am using selenium and ChromeDriverManager to get the last chrome driver automatic as follow code.
    try:
        #print("ChromeDriverManager().install():" + ChromeDriverManager().install())
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=chrome_options)
    except Exception as e:
        print (f"Error: {e}")
        return

It's works before, but someday it's not workable. script will hang in the ChromeDriverManager().install() until I keyboard interrupt it, and I saw the error message as below
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 73, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

I tried to change to firefox, but the symptom is the same.
But I found the same script works normally on my laptop...I think it maybe simething IT block the connect port, how could I know the ChromeDriverManager().install() connect address? Or any idea to fix it?

You can find the the chromedriver file url's for newer versions at googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/known-good-versions-with-downloads.json.
The same issue you've got is mentioned at issue

I believe it's not related to webdriver_manager because in the exception it's saying Failed to establish a new connection which means your proxy is blocking the website to download

therefore the assumption is that you either

have set a bad proxy
or
your instance doesn't have access to the internet 
or
your instance for some other reason blocks the request


Thanks for your answer. Your link gives me more information about this case. It seems the last version of Chromedriver is not listed in the JSON file.

I think I will try to get the last version from Chromedriver known-good-versions-with-downloads.json directly, and then appoint this version to webdriver.Chrome.

reference : https://github.com/SergeyPirogov/webdriver_manager/issues/649
